# Matching Multiline C++ style comments using Regex

Tags: c#, c++, regex, comments

OK, I know it's a recurring issue, however I can't seem to find one single working solution based solely on regex.

So, this is what I've come up with (actually basing it on the 'literal' description of multiline comments in the [C# sharp grammar specification by ECMA](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm)).

```
\/\*(([^\*])+)|([\*]+(?!\/))[\*]+\/
```

However, as you can see it's not working...

**Demo :**

http://regexr.com?38gom

Any ideas? Is this even possible without doing all sorts of hacks? (Well, I mean other than the regex itself... lol)

---

**P.S.** If it is of any informational value, I'm currently developing a lexer/parser/interpreter using Lex/Bison/C/D and obviously multiline comments is a thing to be considered...

Comment: For what language? C++? If yes, skip the rest of my comment, if no -- please don't repeat the mistake of C++, its multiline comments cannot be nested.

Comment: @greenoldmand Thanks for the suggestion. And nope, it's not for C++. It's for one of my own. (Had a look through your project, too, btw! ;-))

Comment: Please see my answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45429626/how-to-match-a-multi-line-comment-with-regex/77328263#77328263.
The provided solution there works for any type of comment with examples on the matching content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the working regex for your provided sample from the [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/?38gom)

```
\/\*+((([^\*])+)|([\*]+(?!\/)))[*]+\/
```

or:

```
\/\*.*?\*\/
```

Comment: Well, well, well. **Yes**, it works! I suppose I'll now have to carefully look into it to see what I was doing wrong...

Comment: Though I didn't understand your regex. It looked complex to me. I have just grouped your `|` inside bracket.

Comment: Well, unfortunately there seems to be still an issue which could not be illustrated by the already existing comments. Have a look here : http://regexr.com?38gop

Comment: use this one `\/\*.*?\*\/` but it will not work if it has `*/` inside the comment.

Answer (score 1):

In case you need this for `flex`, which doesn't implement non-greedy matches, here is one way of writing the regex:

```
[/][*][^*]*[*]+([^/*][^*]*[*]+)*[/]
```

Alternative, not much easier on the eyes:

```
"/*"[^*]*"*"+([^/*][^*]*"*"+)*"/"
```

The <kbd>/</kbd> doesn't need to be quoted. But the stars do, and it seems more consistent. Yet another option is to quote the stars with backslashes, but I find that even harder to read.

---

If you did need this for `flex`/`lex`, you would have been better off putting an appropriate tag, such as [flex-lexer](/questions/tagged/flex-lexer).

Answer (score 1):

In C# I get the best performance with `@"(?s:/\*((?!\*/).)*\*/)"`.

If you like to match all comments (including line comments) use `@"(?>/(/[^\r\n]*|(?s:\*((?!\*/).)*\*/)))"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the short answer

```
\/\*(.*?|\s)*\*\/
```

It'll start from `/*`, then `.*` reads char one by one and `\s` reads white spaces (including new lines) and finally ends at `*/`. This is working for me using C#.