# How to match a multi-line comment with regex

Tags: regex, coffeescript, match, comments, multiline

I want to match a multi-line comment with regex. The comment type is:

```
/*
    This is a comment.
*/
```

I try this code:

```
\/\*(.*?)\*\/
```

The problem image is

[image]

Comment: What tool or language are you using?

Comment: I'm making a grammar package for **Atom text editor**. That's language is **CoffeeScript**.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Atom regex, but the problem appears to be that your regex is not operating in multiline mode.  If you can figure out how to make the regex multiline, it should work.

Comment: I don't know it.

Comment: `[\s\S]*?` instead of `.*?` might help you out here.

Comment: @Sebastian Proske, It match only slash (/).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the regex engine you are using, different rules apply when matching against multiple line strings.

Assuming you are using PCRE (in PHP), this pattern doesn't match because by default the `.` in PCRE does not match newline characters. Use [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/GVKdJb/1) to match the newlines, too:

```
\/\*\s?(.*)\s?\*\/
```

You can also [use your original pattern](https://regex101.com/r/1rv4Tl/1) and specify `/s` (single line) mode but in this case the leading and tailing newline characters will be captured as well.

Comment: In the link does work. But in the Atom text editor doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

### REGEXP FOR SINGLE & MULTI-LINE COMMENTS ( JS / C / C# / JAVA / etc... )

#### Tested in VS Codium and at https://regex101.com

```
\/\*[\s\S\n]*?\*\/|\/\/.*$
```

##### This will correctly match:

```
  // single line comments

  /**
   * multi
   * line
   * comments
   * // including nested inline comments 
   * and without tripping on URL slashes (https://www.example.com)
   */

  /* single line comments written using multi-line delimiters */

  // /* single line comments written using MLDs and within a regular single line comment */
```

###### It can also be useful to prefix the regexp with two additional  `*` (one at the beginning and one after the | ) which will also select all horizontal white-spaces preceding both single and multi-line comments:

```
 *\/\*[\s\S\n]*?\*\/| *\/\/.*$

will_select_this_area_as_well_together_with // the content of a deeply nested comment
```

This can come handy when you have to do some external work on the comments (e.g. translating them). By copying the spaces too, when you'll paste the comments back in the code you can be sure they'll slide back into their original position (column-wise).

That said, in order to avoid errors and make those additional sections more clear, it should be also possible to rewrite it using `[[:space:]]*` like so:

```
[[:space:]]*\/\*[\s\S\n]*?\*\/|[[:space:]]*\/\/.*$
```

however it seems that unfortunately VS Code/Codium do not support this syntax yet, so I'm sticking with the  `*` form.

Hope it helps!

###### Note: if you are testing this on https://regex101.com/ make sure to set the `g` and `m` flags using the switch located after the "hard coded" `/` at the end of the expression.

Comment: if the pattern emerges in a string this fails like this: print("ht tp//website//test"). 
but I found no solutions for this case

Answer (score 0):

This [regex](https://regex101.com/r/iNFt9y/1) should find all comment:

```
\/\*\n((.*?)\n)+\*\/
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved!
I using this code:

```
{
      'begin': '\\/\\*'
      'end': '\\*\\/'
      'name': 'comment.block.documention.mylanguage'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches all multiline comments, like `/* ... */` over multiple lines, even if they include a `*` in them or a `/`.

```
\/\*(([^\*]|\*(?!\/))*)\*\/
```